# Enzyme mock function before componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsx, enzyme

I can mock a function of a component (using Jest, Enzyme and React) like this:

```
let wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
wrapper.instance().load = jest.fn(function(ref) {
  this.setState({ loading: false, notice: {thing: 'thing'} });
});
wrapper.update();
```

My `load` function is actually called by `componentWillMount`. It *seems* that the `componentWillMount` is called *before* I overload the function.

So is there a way to mock a funtion before actually build the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify the Component prototype, instances of that Component will inherit the modified function:

```
Component.prototype.load = jest.fn(function(ref) {
  this.setState({ loading: false, notice: {thing: 'thing'} });
});
let wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more approach, you have access to componentWillMount in your wrapper instance. Once you assign load function as jest.fn you can call componentWillMount from wrapper instance.

```
wrapper.instance().load = jest.fn();
wrapper.instance().componentWillMount();
expect(wrapper.instance().load).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Here is the link to working sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/6ym0r4z96w

Comment: Thank you! The problem is still here: I have to call first `let wrapper = shallow(<Component />)` (that will silently call `componentWillMount` before I re-declare the load function)

Comment: Yes, it will but once you assign jest.fn to class function you are invoking componentWillMount again. Since you are just doing functional testing after invocation of willMount your load should be called.